# using filter in ModelChoiceField from another ModelChoiceField

Tags: python, django

I've created a model in django using ForeignKeys

I've 2 models:

```
class Regions(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

class Zones(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    region = models.ForeignKey(Regions)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
```

And a form:

```
class GraphForm(forms.Form):
    regions = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Regions.objects.all(),required=False)
    zone = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Zones.objects.all(),required=False)
```

Is there any Django app that while you choose a region in a form, you only see the modelchoicefiled from the same region?

Thx,
Yuval

Comment: it is not clear for me what you would like to do. what are the 2 elements of your form?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Interdependent dropdowns in django using Modelform and jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121132/how-to-get-interdependent-dropdowns-in-django-using-modelform-and-jquery)