# Issue filling select box via ajax call in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am running into an issue creating cascading select boxes (backend Django-though I think this portion is mostly worked out).  I have the following javascript code adapted from this stackoverflow [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121132/how-to-get-interdependent-dropdowns-in-django-using-modelform-and-jquery).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select[name=experiment]').change(function(){
    experiment_id = $(this).val();
    request_url = '/admin/get_measurements/' + experiment_id + '/';
    $.ajax({
        url: request_url,
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function(){
                $('select[name=measurement_a]').append('<option value="' + this.key + '">' + this.value +'</option>');
        //          $('select[name=measurement_a]').append($("<option />").val(this.key).text(this.value))
            });
        },
        return: false
})
})
});
```

In my project I select an experiment which triggers a call to "get_measurements" function and receive a list of "measurements" which should populate the measurement select box.  Currently when I select the experiment I see the json response as expected:

```
{1: "MyFirstMeasurment", 2: "MySecondMeasurement"}
```

The measurement select box received 2 new selections however, both of them have the text "undefined" as opposed to "MyFirstMeasurement" and "MySecondMeasurement".  I am guessing this is something simple in my code, Thank you for the help, let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Assuming an url like this `/admin/get_measurements/1`...that should return only one data set...or not?

Comment: Hi Robert yes just one dataset as a dictionary

Comment: Show me the result in the success call of `console.log(data);`

Comment: Object {1: "AAB", 2: "AAC"}...The AAB and AAC are the actual values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I needed to do a couple of things to fix this, thanks for the help and hints.  Here is the final code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select[name=experiment]').change(function(){
    experiment_id = $(this).val();
    request_url = '/admin/get_measurements/' + experiment_id + '/';
    $.ajax({
        url: request_url,
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function(key, value){

                $('select[name=measurement_a]').append("<option value='" + value + "'>" + value +</option>");

            });
        },
        return: false
})
})
});
```