# Dependent drop down in Django Form

Tags: django, django-forms

I am new to django, and I am having trouble with dependent drop down lists in django forms. I have 2 model classes, `MainCategory` and `SubCategory`, where `SubCategory` has `maincategory` as the foreign key. I am trying to create a form such that, when a category is selected, the subcategories for it should populate in the drop down.
I have tried [How to get Interdependent dropdowns in django using Modelform and jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121132/how-to-get-interdependent-dropdowns-in-django-using-modelform-and-jquery) this solution, and it works after making some changes. But, I was wondering if any other django inbuilt solution exists?

Models.py

```
class MainCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Category", max_length = 50)

class SubCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Sub category", max_length = 50)
    mainCategory = models.ForeignKey(MainCategory)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've modified your question to add some formatting and fix some grammar, but the question could really use some more information from you. Feel free to edit the answers to some of these questions into your question. Do you have any forms already written? What is the code for them? Do you want the second dropdown to update automatically, on the same page, or should the user submi the form before they are displayed? Where will this form be used (the Django admin, etc.)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Interdependent dropdowns in django using Modelform and jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121132/how-to-get-interdependent-dropdowns-in-django-using-modelform-and-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

For this issue i use [django-smart-select](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects) good and easy for this job, include examples.