# Django related filter on choice

Tags: django

Is there a way to update other choice when I select one choice in admin or model, I dont want to use view or form.

Example: when I choise the country just show the states related to the selected county

[image]

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121132/how-to-get-interdependent-dropdowns-in-django-using-modelform-and-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Interdependent dropdowns in django using Modelform and jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121132/how-to-get-interdependent-dropdowns-in-django-using-modelform-and-jquery)