# Django. How to make a condition for hide/show fields in the form so that it depends on the backend?

Tags: javascript, html, django, database

I want to make a condition under which it will not be necessary to change the code if the data in the database has been deleted. Now I have a simple condition:

```
$('#category_id').change(function () {
        var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
        var valueSelected = $(this).val();

        if (valueSelected === '1') {
          $('#rooms_id').hide();
          $('#series_id').hide();            
        } else if (valueSelected === '2') {
          $('#rooms_id').hide();
          $('#series_id').hide();
        } else {
          $('#rooms_id').show();
          $('#series_id').show();
        }
      });
```

That is, when you select a specific category, unnecessary fields are hidden. But, if you delete the categories in the database, and the categoties is added again not in the order as they were before, the condition will stop working. Because select will be different.

```
<div class="col-md-3 mb-3">       
                <label class="sr-only">Categories</label>
                <select name="category" class="form-control" id="category_id">
                  <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Categories</option>
                  {% for category in categories %}
                    <option value="{{ category.pk }}">{{ category.name }}</option>
                  {% endfor %}
                </select>
              </div>
```

This fields must be hide:

```
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label class="sr-only">Комнаты</label>
                  <select name="rooms" class="form-control" id="rooms_id">
                    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Комнаты</option>
                    {% for key, value in room_choices.items %}
                      <option value="{{ key }}">{{ value }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </select>
                </div>

              <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label class="sr-only">Серия</label>
                <select name="series" class="form-control" id="series_id">
                  <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Серия</option>
                  {% for series in series %}
                    <option value="{{ series.pk }}">{{ series.name }}</option>
                  {% endfor %}
                </select>
              </div>
```

Now everything works only in this sequence, but if you add categories to the database in a different order, then nothing works, because this solution is not entirely correct. Pleace, help :)

Comment: Hm, could you clarify "the flow is added again in the wrong order as they were before"?

Comment: I haven't done chained dropdowns in Django, but this looks like a job for Ajax. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121132/how-to-get-interdependent-dropdowns-in-django-using-modelform-and-jquery

Comment: "the categoties is added again not in the order as they were before"