# Django display content based on dropdown select

Tags: django, html-select

I am new in Django.
I want to display content based on dropdown selection.
In this example i want to show all the workshops data from the location selected in the dropdown.
Is it possible to achieve that without reloading the page? or if it must reload the page, is it possible to stay on current view after reloading the page?

Thank you.

I have tried to use post method and use onChange attribute on my forms.
It successfully reload the page but the workshops content is not shown, the dropdown selection go back to default '--- Choose your location ---' and the page go back to the top.

Below is the code of the forms

```py
class LocationForm(forms.Form):
        location = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='', queryset=Location.objects.all(), empty_label="--- Choose your location ---",
            widget=forms.Select(
                attrs={'id': 'ddlLocation', 'name':'ddlLocation', 'class':'selectpicker', 'data-live-search':'true', 'data-size':'5', 'onChange':'frLocation.submit();' }
            )
        )
```

Below is the code of the class

```py
class HomeView2(ListView):
    template_name = 'myapp/index.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form_location = LocationForm()
        location_id = request.GET.get('location_id')
        workshops = Workshop.objects.filter(location_id=location_id).order_by('workshop_name')
        args = {'form_location':form_location, 'workshops':workshops}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def post(self,request):
        form_location = LocationForm()
        location_id = request.GET.get('location_id')
        workshops = Workshop.objects.filter(location_id=location_id).order_by('workshop_name')
        args = {'form_location':form_location, 'workshops':workshops}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

and in index.html

```html
<section class="page-section" id="services">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="text-center mt-0">At Your Service</h2>
      <hr class="divider my-4">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 text-center">
          <div class="mt-5">
            <i class="fas fa-4x fa-wrench text-primary mb-4"></i>
            <h3 class="h4 mb-2">Select location</h3>
            <form id="frLocation" name="frLocation" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{form_location}}
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 text-center">
              <div class="mt-5">
                <form id="frWorkshop">
                  {% for workshop in workshops %}
                    <p>Workshop: {{workshop.workshop_name}}</p>
                  {% endfor %}
                </form>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: If you don't want to switch page, you need to use javascript and make an ajax (get) request to fetch the workshops belonging to a selected location. On the django side, you would write a view that receives the request and returns a `JsonResponse` with the data you need to show the user. On the client side, your ajax success function then processes that data and manipulates the DOM to display it as HTML. Alternatively your Django view can return a partial HTML snippet (using a normal template) that your javascript just inserts in the page at the right place.

Comment: If you don't have loads of data, you could just add it all to the template, hiding the workshops initially, giving each one an attribute for the location. Then with javascript you'd unhide the workshops depending on the selected location.

Comment: Something in the lines of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121132/how-to-get-interdependent-dropdowns-in-django-using-modelform-and-jquery)

Comment: @dirkgroten I have tried the answers from the link but still can't achieve what i want.

Can sombebody show the ajax code for my case?