# Multiple Dependent Dropdown in Django

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax, bootstrap-4

I Need two pair dependent dropdown

1. Field name: Country
2. Field name: State
   note - Field name: Country and Field name: state should be dependent dropdown
3. Field name: Product(Vegitable,Fruit)
4. Field name: name of product

note - Field name: Product(Vegitable,Fruit) and name of product should be dependent dropdown

if I select Vegetable then Cabadge,Patato has to reflect and i select Fruit then Apple, Orange has to reflect
5. Field name : Status
Category are Testing1,Testing2,Testing3
6. DateTime : mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss

Request please create small crud

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121132/how-to-get-interdependent-dropdowns-in-django-using-modelform-and-jquery

Comment: I saw the code which is given in link but my requirement is different.
i need dependent drop down between country and city,  Product and name of product. and one more Signal dropdown

Comment: the idea is the same, you have to make multiple implementation.

Comment: if i will go to HTML File Fields should come such as  Country , City, Product, Name of Product, Date&Time

Comment: I tried but showing some error

Comment: below is error 
OperationalError at /
no such table: myapp_processmodel

Comment: Could please prepare mini project based on my requirement. I tried a lot but not able to do it.